# C++ - Comparing data types between templates and classes

Tags: c++, templates, nodes

I'm currently working with nodes of type template, I run into a problem when I compare those nodes with data from a normal class. The 2 data types that aren't matching up is the line `root->data = item;` `root` is `Node<string> *TreeParser::root`, where as `item` is `const Node <string> &`. When looking at previous work where both classes are type template this works. However, when I change the class to a nontemplate type this code no longer works. How can I get these 2 different types of data to talk to each other with out changing my class to type template. Here is my example code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* lLink;
    Node* rLink;
};

class TreeParser{
public:
    void insert(const Node<string>& item);
private:
    Node<string>* root{ nullptr };
};

void TreeParser::insert(const Node<string>& item){
    if (root == nullptr){
        root = new Node<string>();
        root->data = item;
        return;
    }
    else
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
root->data = item;
```

This `root` is a pointer to a `Node<string>`

```
root = new Node<string>();
```

So, pop quiz time: what is `root->data`. The right answer is, of course, it's a `std::string`. The template parameter is `std::string`, so with the template declaring a:

```
T data;
```

With `T` being the aforementioned `std::string`, we there conclude that in this statement:

```
root->data = item;
```

The `root->data` portion is a `std::string`. Now the next item for discussion is what exactly is the `item` here, well it is declared as:

```
const Node<string>& item
```

So, therefore, your `item` is a `Node<string>`.

So, in summary:

```
root->data = item;
```

attempts to assign a `Node<String>` to a `string`.

That, of course, is not going to work. The only thing that can be assigned to a `std::string` would be another `std::string`, or a `const char *`, perhaps, or a few other things that are not important here.

Your likely intention is:

```
root->data = item.data;
```

But, any place you can find some other `std::string` will work equally well here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, makes so much sense when you go through it that way.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `root->data` is a `string` whereas `item` is a `Node<string>` reference. These are obviously incompatible types. If you really want to avoid templating `TreeParser` you should use the copy or move constructor of `Node` for the creation of `root`. Something like: `root = new Node<string>(item);`

Oh yes, and to forgo the usual comment, use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead of a naked pointer.